# Lennard-Jones induced pseudo-molecules

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, history, collision, many-body

It can be [shown](http://wesscholar.wesleyan.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1207&context=etd_hon_theses) that the [Lennard-Jones potential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lennard-Jones_potential) - which describes the interaction between particles in non-ideal gases - gives rise to pseudo-molecules: after a triple "collision" of three (classical) particles under suitable conditions two of them can rotate around each other, forming something like a pseudo-molecule. This is similar to the process of [asteroid capture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asteroid_capture) under gravitation where also a third body is necessary to carry away the excess energy.

Under realistic circumstances those pseudo-molecules won't be very stable and probably don't play an important role in the thermodynamical treatment of non-ideal gases. This might have to do with the fact that three-particle collisions are too rare and that accordingly only two-body interactions are considered.

But assume that three-particle collisions that give rise to pseudo-molecules occur often enough and that the pseudo-molecules are sufficiently stable.

The following questions came to my mind:

> 1. Can ever greater clusters  emerge?
> 2. What can be said statistically resp. thermodynamically about the
>      distribution of cluster sizes?
> 3. How would a given distribution (e.g. Poisson) affect the macroscopic
>      properties (especially: of **which** macroscopically observable properties) of such a thermodynamical system?

---

Historical motivation: I try to empathize with (idealized) ancient atomists that knew nothing about chemical bonding and did believe only in elastic collision and contact interaction among atoms, i.e. some sort of glueing. An appropriate Lennard-Jones potential - with a sufficiently deep and narrow potential well - can model both. Which kinds of structures can emerge in such a system?

The other way around: What would the atomists have to have known and considered to recognize that their model does not work?

Comment: As far as large clusters go, while I'm sure it's possible for delicate exotic clusters to assemble under careful conditions, atoms and molecules bonk and crash into each other so often in the condensed phase (or even just in room-temperature air) that they'd have no chance of surviving for any reasonable period of time, unless they were actually stable against falling apart.

Comment: But when we think - theoretically and counterfactually - of a Lennard-Jones-like potential with a really *deep* and really *narrow* potential well, from which really stable clusters arise? (To make things clear: I am happy with handwaving arguments for the *impossibility* of such situations.)

Comment: I did a MD simulation once with particles that only interacted vs LJ.  Varying σ, ϵ, and temperature led to a variety of clusters forming.  The pair correlation functions of these "clustered" systems matched those of liquid or solid PCFs.

Comment: I found this one: [Van der Waals molecules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_molecules). This answers my question to some extent.

Comment: How are these clusters different from bulk liquid or the liquid-vapor interface? Yes, they are small, and thus their thermodynamics might be slightly different (Tolman corrections), but as far as the basic physical principles go, I would see these clusters as basically liquid (which is why getting the g(r) of a liquid from MD seems expected, as @Nick computed). I would further expect any clusters to nucleate together and finally phase separate into liquid-vapor coexistence (and from nucleation theory you can estimate the sizes of smallest stable nucleation clusters).